# GAN failure to converge with both discriminator and generator loss go to 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm training a GAN network by Keras in Tensorflow 2.0. I can get some reasonable yet not well-looked results, until I try to add BatchNormalization layers.
I know the training of GAN is very sensitive with many reasons to cause divergence, but I want to know what is going wrong under this case: both the discriminator / generator loss drop to zero.

My network is like the common examples of DCGAN:

```
===== Generator =====  
Input(128)  
Dense(16384) => ReLU  
Reshape(4 x 4 x 1024)  
Conv2DTranspose(8 x 8 x 512, kernel=4, stride=2) => ReLU  
Conv2DTranspose(16 x 16 x 256, kernel=4, stride=2) => ReLU  
Conv2DTranspose(32 x 32 x 128, kernel=4, stride=2) => ReLU  
Conv2DTranspose(64 x 64 x 3, kernel=4, stride=2, activation=sigmoid)  
===== Discriminator =====  
Conv2D(32 x 32 x 64, kernel=3, stride=2) => LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)  
Conv2D16 x 16 x 128, kernel=3, stride=2) => LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)  
Conv2D(8 x 8 x 256, kernel=3, stride=2) => LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)  
Conv2D(4 x 4 x 512, kernel=3, stride=2) => LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)  
Flatten(8192)  
Dense(1, activation=sigmoid)
```

I also follow the suggested training settings of DCGAN:

```
Kernel init = RandomNormal, stddev=0.02  
Optimizer = Adam, beta1 = 0.5  
Learning rate = 0.0002
```

My dataset contains 2048 Images with a specified class.
On my first try, I train the network by the following order:
1. Draw 128 real samples with small spatial augmentation.
2. Generate 128 fake samples by current generator.
3. **Stack the samples and train the discriminator by these 256 samples as a batch**
4. Generate 256 random latent data vectors
5. **Train the generator by these 256 vectors as a batch**

The loss values are averaged and reported after every epoch.

I get fair results from these settings. The discriminator loss is in 0.60-0.70 and the generator loss is in 0.70-1.00, but the improvement of quality seems to be slow. So I add batch normalization layer to all (transposed) convolutions except the one at generator output, as commonly suggested.
After adding batch normalization, the training loss becomes much unstable, but do not directly diverge. The discriminator loss drops to 0.20-0.40 and the generator loss varies in 1.00-3.00.
I have tried momentum = 0.8 or 0.9 and they give similar behavior.

Then I try to NOT stack the real/fake samples in a single batch, but rather train the discriminator by 128 real samples, then 128 fake samples, and still use the batch normalization layers.
Under this setting, the discriminator and generator loss both drop rapidly after the first epoch and toward 0. The generated images look like strong color noises at every pixel, and the predicted probabilities (after sigmoid) of these noisy images are all close to 1.0.
If I remove all batch normalization layers but just train the real/fake samples separately, this problem does not happen.

If the generator can fool the discriminator by noisy images and get high probability, why the discriminator loss can still be very close to zero after its training? Does batch normalization layer have some bad effect under this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is also called **Saturation Problem**, it means that the discriminator trains beyond the limit. In simple words, it happened because of the vanishing gradient problem of GANs. If you want to understand the mathematics behind this I encourage you to read this [article](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/gan-what-is-wrong-with-the-gan-cost-function-6f594162ce01) carefully.